# Horizontal scrollbar hides content of ApplicationControlBar

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have an application control bar at the bottom of my Flex application (with attributes width="100%", dock="false", left="0", bottom="0", height="50"). It contains a lot of elements (like buttons and labels). The width of the SWF is the width of the browser.

When the user makes the width of the browser window smaller, after a certain point, the components on the application control bar gets "squished": they are forced on top of each other. And so, it becomes confusing and ugly. To ensure that that doesn't happen, I've set the minWidth attribute to a value so that it'll always display the components without them overlapping each other.

But then, a horizontal scrollbar appears and hides the bottom half of the application control bar.

I've googled and I found this article: [flex verticalscrollpolicy bug](http://www.nbilyk.com/flex-scrollpolicy-bug) (referenced by this SO question: [Flex: Prevent scrollbar from covering content when automatically displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292826/flex-prevent-scrollbar-from-covering-content-when-automatically-displayed)).

But that seems to apply only to a fixed size component. My component's width is a percentage. Any ideas on how to have the horizontal scrollbar appear and have it not cover up the application control bar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this happens when the ApplicationControlBar is fixed at the bottom: bottom=0 and left=0. The easiest solution is to make the bar a lot taller (that'll push the content way higher than the scrollbar height). But that makes it kinda ugly.

So another solution: in the MXML file, I capture the Resize event. And in that function, I do this:

```
if (width < bar.minWidth) // width is the width of the SWF
{
    bar.height = ORIGINAL_SIZE + 10;
    hbox.setStyle("verticalAlign", "top");
    hbox.setStyle("verticalCenter", -10);
} else {
    // normal case
    box.height = ORIGINAL_SIZE;
    hbox.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
    hbox.setStyle("verticalCenter", 0);
}
```

And the horizontal scrollbar doesn't hide the content anymore! Also, the Resize event doesn't get triggered when the bar has a minWidth & the width of the stage is less than that.

Answer (score 0):

See if adding the following code to the overriden validateSize method (as in the [scrollpolicy bug](http://www.nbilyk.com/flex-scrollpolicy-bug) page you linked to) solves the problem.

```
if (width < measuredWidth)
{
  height = normal-height + height-of-the-horizontal-scrollbar;
}
else
  height = normal-height;
```

(Find the normal height of the application control bar and the scroll bar (trace them out) and use those values).

Comment: Nope that doesn't work. I guess you are trying to increase the height, in hopes that the content will be more visible -- but the actual height doesn't really change and a vertical scrollbars show up, which kinda makes things worse :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had this come up today and I slightly tweaked sri's if statement like this:

```
if (buttonContainer.horizontalScrollbar)
{
    // Change height & style properties
}
else
{
    // Return to original properties.
}
```