# when container's one of scroll apears, other is added automatically can we avoid this?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, scroll

if container like VBox have autoScrollPolicy for both scrolls. if `VerticalScrollBar` is added, why the **`horizontalScrollBar` automatically added**.. is there any option to avoid the `horizontalScrollBar` addition to container.. without using `horizontalScrollPolicy="off"`

Comment: Post your problematic code, because this is specific to whatever way you chose to do your layout, and normally the horizontal scroll doesn't appear.

Comment: This is when VBox children does not fit on given area, vertical scroll is shown automatically. Vertical scroll takes some horizontal space of VBox, then some elements might not fit horizontally anymore. Now VBox shows horizontal scroll.

Comment: The same problem has been already discussed:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292826/flex-prevent-scrollbar-from-covering-content-when-automatically-displayed

Answer (score 1):

setStyle('horizontalScrollPolicy', ScrollPolicy.OFF);